# Hacer un for en una sola línea en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, condiciones

Sé que hay una manera de hacer los if en una sola línea, tal que así:

```
a = 10
print(4) if a == 10 else False
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto con un bucle for? Además, ¿cómo hago para meter varias líneas (que estarían dentro del for o del if) en la misma línea, usando esto?

Gracias.

Comment: `for i in array: print(i)`

Comment: Malher400, sería de ayuda saber que es lo que quieres poner dentro del **for**, como también lo sería, conocer el motivo.

Comment: Puedes apoyarte en esta respuesta también: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459681/for-loop-one-line-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que te refieres a list comprehensions.

```
nueva_lista = [print(x) for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6] if x < 5]
```

El resultado sería:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Cabe mencionar que esto se usa para listas, no para bucles, pero puedes haberte confundido porque iterar sobre una lista es efectivamente usar un bucle.

**Edit:**
Importante aclaración que el código siempre crea una lista. En ese ejemplo hay un `print` para que "veas" lo que ocurre, pero en una situación real el código sería:

```
nueva_lista = [x for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6] if x < 5]
```

Comment: No es correcto. Aunque lo que se muestra por pantalla al ejecutar ese código es efectivamente los números que muestras, el resultado que se almacena en `nueva_lista`  es en cambio `[None, None, None, None]`, por la razón que explico en mi respuesta. El resultado correcto lo obtienes con `nueva_lista = [x for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6] if x<5 ]`

Comment: nueva_lista es None de hecho tu codigo funcionaria solo asi `[print(x) for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6] if x < 5]` definistes una variable que no almacena nada

Comment: Incorrecto, el código hace exactamente lo que quería que hiciera. **Explico:** el ejemplo lo he hecho únicamente para imprimir los resultados ya que quien ha hecho esta pregunta ha puesto el ejemplo con `prints` en su pregunta inicial. Son vuestras sugerencias las que no serían válidas ya que no hacen `print` de los items de la lista. En un ejemplo real obviamente el `print` que yo he ejecutado se eliminaría (es bastante obvio para cualquiera). Añadí la variable para que el usuario que ha hecho la pregunta sepa que puede almacenar una list comprehension en variables para su futuro uso.

Comment: De acuerdo con que has hecho unos print, siguiendo el ejemplo del usuario, pero esa forma de programar es un _antipatrón_ y como mínimo deberías explicar cómo es la forma correcta, pues es evidente que el usuario que preguntó no lo sabe (su ejemplo usando una expresión ternaria para hacer un print es otro _antipatrón_). Por otro lado, guardar los resultados en una lista en este caso no tiene sentido porque sólo estás guardando `None`s, y no los números que imprimes.

Answer (score 4):

Varias instrucciones en una sola línea se separan con punto y coma `;`

Por ejemplo:

`for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]: print (i); print (i*i); print (i*i*i)`

Pero no se recomienda hacer esto, según el manual de estilo de Python ([PEP 8 Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

Puede ver también esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line/

Comment: Gracias, no conocía lo de los ; :)

Answer (score 2):

`print(4) if a == 10 else False` no es "un if en una línea", es el operador ternario.

No es una instrucción, sino una expresión que produce un resultado y que típicamente se usa al lado derecho de una igualdad para asignar ese resultado. El resultado de la expresión completa es, o bien lo que sale de evaluar lo que aparece antes de `if` (si la condición es cierta), o bien lo que sale de evaluar lo que hay tras el `else` (si la condición es falsa).

Como digo, suele usarse en asignaciones, por ejemplo así:

```
b = c/a if a!=0 else "Error"
```

En este caso la variable `b` recibirá el resultado de `c/a` si `a` es distinto de cero, o bien la cadena `"Error"` si `a` es cero.

En tu caso estás "abusando" de esa expresión al no usarla para evaluar ni asignar nada, sino para hacer un `print()`, ya que tu expresión:

```
print(4) if a == 10 else False
```

produce un resultado que no estás asignando. El resultado es `None` (que es lo que siempre retorna `print()`) si `a` vale 10, o bien `False` si `a` es distinto de 10.

No se recomienda usar el operador ternario de esta forma. Es mucho más normal y legible esta otra:

```
if a==10:
   print(4)
```

De este modo tampoco tienes que poner ese artificial `else False`.

Si por razones incomprensibles tiene que ser una sola línea, aún puedes hacer esto:

```
if a == 10: print(4)
```

En cuanto al "for en una sola línea", cabe decir lo mismo. Por ejemplo para imprimir los elementos de una lista, puedes hacerlo así:

```
for elemento in lista: print(elemento)
```

Pero no veo ninguna razón para hacerlo en una sola línea, resultando más legible esto otro:

```
for elemento in lista:
    print(elemento)
```

En otra respuesta te han hablado de las *list comprehensions*, que son una sintaxis especialmente cómoda para **crear** listas a base de iterar por otras. Básicamente esta línea:

```
mitades = [ dato/2 for dato in lista if dato%2 == 0]
```

equivale al siguiente bucle python:

```
mitades = []
for dato in lista:
    if dato%2==0:
        mitades.append(dato)
```

En este caso sí considero que la versión *comprehension* merece la pena, pues es más compacta y hasta más legible.

Sin embargo **no debes** usar *list comprehensions* para reemplazar a bucles que no sean para crear listas, abusando de la construcción como hiciste con el operador ternario. Por ejemplo, lo siguiente no está bien visto:

```
[ print(elemento) for elemento in datos ]
```

Realmente esto es un abuso de la sintaxis, pues lo que estás haciendo es crear una lista nueva (pues todo va entre corchetes) con los resultados de evaluar `print(elemento)` para cada elemento de `datos`. Estos resultados son siempre `None` (¿he dicho ya que `print()` retorna siempre `None`?) por lo que al final has creado una lista llena de `None`. Esa lista no la asignas a ninguna variable, luego será destruída por el recolector de basura de Python.

¿Por qué esa forma retorcida? ¿Qué tiene de malo el clásico y sencillo `for elemento in lista: print(elemento)`, que no crea listas llenas de `None` intermedias para después destruirlas?

Comment: Pregunta de novato:
¿Sería posible/correcto utilizar esta técnica en la creación de diccionarios?
He visto aquí https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html que puedes iterar una lista que contiene listas y se me ha venido a la cabeza esta pregunta pero no encuentro nada, quizá porque no se pueda o no se deba..

Comment: @Borjinha10 Sí, puedes usar una sintaxis análoga para crear diccionarios, pero en un diccionario tienes que especificar la clave y el valor. Por ejemplo, para crear un diccionario en el que las claves sean los números del 1 al 10 y los correspondientes valores sean el doble de cada clave puedes hacer `{k: k*2 for k in range(1,11) }`. Otro ejemplo. Dado un diccionario `d` crear otro solo con los elementos de  valor mayor de 5: `{k: v for k,v in d.items() if v>5}`

Comment: Gracias @abulafia por la respuesta, voy a trastear porque parece interesante.